# How to create drawable layer-list for android in Eclipse?

Tags: android

I create resource drawable `layer-list` but i can't find?
[image]

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesn't show the `layer-list` option in that dialog for me either so i guess it's one of the `ADT plugin` + Eclipse bugs(or feature:) ).

A `layer-list` it's just a xml file in the `drawable` folder that has a `layer-list` element in it so you could make it manually:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
       // the items of the layer-list, you coul have many items in the layer-list
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).